# Php foreach and echo inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Good day to everyone:). I just want to  ask how can I do **php** `foreach` and `echo` values inside the **javascript**, because I want the **javascript** to be a dynamic.
Here is the static js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){


        if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
            $(".1").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
            $(".2").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="3"){
            $(".3").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="4"){
            $(".4").toggle();
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

and this what I want to happen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

<?php foreach($data as $field): ?> 

        if($(this).attr("value")=="<?php echo $field->ID);?>" ){
            $(".<?php echo $field->ID);?>").toggle();
        }

<?php endforeach; ?>       
    });
});
</script>
```

the `ID` values form the database are `1,2,3,4`. That would be all. Thank You!

Comment: Very bad coding practice..

Comment: It's hard to tell why that won't work since we don't know what the value of `$data` is. You should look at the generated JS to see what the result is.

Comment: I really wouldn't use PHP for this at all and just do: `$("." + this.value).toggle()` instead.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work, the php is run first, which should generate the js. As @Quentin said, look in the js for the problem.

Comment: @Dagon — Why can't it work? There's no attempt to pass data from JS back to PHP that I can see. Since PHP runs first, that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can push all the values to a js array and than do a loop on js array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    my_values = Array;
    <?php foreach($data as $field): ?> 
        my_values.push ("<?php echo $field; ?>");
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        // java script loop here
        for ( var i in my_values)
        {
          if($(this).attr("value")== i )
         {
           $("."+this.value).toggle();
         }
      } 
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: He could, but why would that be better than the current approach?

Comment: it will be a bit cleaner and more readable by separating both codes.

Comment: That's a bit subjective (especially as you haven't shown half the new version of the code). That said, possibly a better question would be: How does it fix the problem with the current code? (For that matter, what is the problem with the current code?)